# Nhibernate connection error

Tags: nhibernate

I am using nhibernate 3.1.0, oracle 10g express edition and asp.net 3.5 MVC. I am getting error "ora 06413: connection not open" please help me to solve this problem. My Connection properties are:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">User ID=user;Password=pwd;Data Source=localhost:1521/XE</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a stab here - but it looks like your connection string isn't formatted properly.

The connection string you're using appears to be for "XE Client", but I don't think that's what NHibernate uses. I'd be willing to be NHibernate is going to use something more similar to one of the Microsoft connection strings shown on that page.

In all the oracle connection strings I see at [ConnectionStrings.com/Oracle](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) it seems the properties "User ID", "Password", and "Data Source" are not valid.

You could also reference this example of using NHibernate with an Oracle server: http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/using-oracle-odp-with-nhibernate-from-a-c-class-library/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ***Oracle 10g*** is a bit finicky on 64-bit systems. The best option seemed to be switching to MySQL.
the usage of MySQL also provide more features in hibernate